# What type of quick release do I need for this Sunpak tripod?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, equipment-identification

I've inherited a Sunpak tripod without the quick release pad/plate thing (please correct my terminology).

I'm looking to find the quick release plate for this. What is this style/size called?  I cannot find any markings on the tripod other than "SUNPAK". No model number, nothing.

Also, how standardized are quick release plates? Would all Sunpak tripods use the same one? I can't find documentation for them.

[image: Sunpak Tripod]
[image: Sunpak Tripod Quick Release]

As user xiota noted below, it would seem that a 44x44mm universal quick release might work, but I tried it and it was just barely too large.

Comment: They are not all the same, is there a model number on the tripod anywhere? (If the head isn't permanently attached, you'll want the one off the head, not the legs.)

Comment: @LightBender - I'm not seeing any markings anywhere other than "SUNPAK". I looked good 'n hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheap tripods typically use compatible quick-release plates.  Search for **"universal tripod quick release"** on your favorite auction site.

The base is tapered, so it's not clear from your images whether the plate pictured below would or wouldn't fit.  If the "universal" plate is too large, you're unlikely to find one that's the right size.  The tripods are too cheap for the manufacturers to sell custom-fitted plates separately.  The scheme appears to be to get people to buy new tripods when the plate is lost or broken.

Since the plate you tried is "just barely too large", you could try shaving off a bit to get it to fit.  If you have a carving knife and know how to use it safely, that would be the way to go.  Sanding is also an option, but keep a vacuum cleaner handy to avoid getting dust everywhere.

You may be [better off](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186789/etymology-of-throw-good-money-after-bad) adding it to the growing collection of tripods with missing quick-release plates at your local thrift store.  Or perhaps picking up a sturdier tripod from their collection that will work with a "universal" plate.

[image: universal quick release]
[image: measurements]

Comment: Based on the tape measure in the small images included in the OP, the receiver on the tripod appears to be less than 44mm x 44m.

Comment: I just got a friend to bring that exact thing over, 44x44mm. No luck. It should be noted that while the outer dimension is 44mm, the bracket is beveled/"dovetailed", so the smaller dimension comes to around 42mm. That was still too large though.

Comment: @xiota - I took the universal one and cut a bunch of plastic off using tin snips and side cutters until it fit in there. There was just enough plastic left for it to lock in place, so that makes it a win!